# Creating Java Spring Boot endpoint to obtain list of objects as json

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, endpoint

I'm trying to create an endpoint that returns a list of objects as a JSON.

The current object structure is as follows:

```
units: [
        {
         id: #,
         order: #,
         name: ""
         concepts: [
                    {
                     id: #
                     name: ""
                    },
                    ...
         ]
        },
        ...
]
```

A list of units which have 4 attributes, one of them being another list of objects with 2 otehr attributes. This is kind of the result I'm looking to obtain.

I was currently trying to do the following in my `UnitController`:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
public @ResponseBody List<Unit> getUnits() {
    return unitService.findAll();
}
```

But whenever I run the app and try `curl localhost:8080/units`, I get nothing. Could this be because of another method I have in the controller, like this one:

```
@RequestMapping("")
public String index(Map<String, Object> model) {
    List<Unit> units = unitService.findAll();
    model.put("units", units);
    return "units/index";
}
```

Could someone kindly help me through this and tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'd really appreciate it.

**EDIT**

Ok so I moved the annotation on top of the class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/units", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
public class UnitController extends BaseController {
...
}
```

And tried the endpoint like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/units.json")
public @ResponseBody List<Unit> getUnits() {
    return unitService.findAll();
}
```

But it `curl localhost:8080/units.json` is still giving me no response.

Also forgot to mention that my `application.properties` file doesn't have a `server.contextPath` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That might be because of no `@RequestMapping` annotation on controller. Spring boot needs mapping to figure out which method needs to be called when a `REST` API request is sent. E.g. You need the following on `UnitController` class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, value = "/units")
public class UnitController {
```

If your controller class already has that, then you need to define another mapping for methods, specifying request method and optionally, mapping. E.g.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, value = "/units")
public class UnitController {

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public List<Unit> method1(){..}

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public List<Unit> method2(){..}

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/unit")
   public List<Unit> method3(){..}
}
```

For the above example:

- Sending a `GET` request to /units will result in invocation of `method1`
- Sending a `POST` request to /units will result in invocation of `method2`
- Sending a `GET` request to /units/unit will result in invocation of `method3`

If your `application.properties` file has `server.contextPath` property defined then it needs to be appended to the baseurl, e.g. `<host>:<port>/<contextPath>`